# No internet connection in UTM (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 via UTM on my M1, and recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 since I needed it.

The problem is that while I had no problem with internet connection with 20.04, there is no internet connection in 18.04. An interesting thing I found was that the internet seems to work in "Console interface" since I could run `sudo apt update` with no problem, but if I run it in "Graphic interface", the error code is as follows:

```
Err:1 http://kr.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionicInRelease
  Could not resolve 'kr.ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://kr .ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'kr.ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://kr.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'kr.ports.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http: //ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ports.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://kr.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/InReleas
e  Could not resolve 'kr.ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://kr.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease
   Could not resolve 'kr.ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http: //kr.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease
   Could not resolve 'kr.ports.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-security/InRelease
   Could not resolve 'ports. ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

First, I tried to solve the `sudo apt update` error above by adding `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` and `nameserver 8.8.8.8` `nameserver 8.8.4.4` in `$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and `$ vi /etc/resolv.conf` respectively, but I still couldn't solve the problem.

I then checked `lshw -C network` in both 18.04 and 20.04, and the outputs are almost the same except that the `ip` is missing and `link=no` instead of `yes` in the last line in the output of 18.04.

```
@tro:~$ lshw -C network 
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Virtio network device
       vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
       physical id: a
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=virtio-pci latency=0
       resources: irq:39 ioport:1140(size=32) memory:1005f000-1005ffff memory:10054000-10057fff memory:10000000-1003ffff
     *-virtio3 DISABLED
          description: Ethernet interface
          physical id: 0
          bus info: virtio@3
          logical name: enp0s10
          serial: e6:a6:51:a2:02:a0
          capabilities: ethernet physical
          configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=virtio_net driverversion=1.0.0 link=no multicast=yes
```

I've been struggling with this problem, and really wish to solve this soon.....